# Pie chart display Non-Null Values

Tags: android, pie-chart, achartengine

I am working on Pie charts using AChartEngine library. Here I want to disable chart values to show on charts, but only those whose content value is 0.If anyone known this please share to me.

### Codings:

```
                    pchart=ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this,buildCategoryDataset("Daily Basis", values),renderer);

                    re.addView(pchart);
                    }
                }
```

### BuildCategory Renderer:

```
 protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
        DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setShowLegend(true);

        renderer.setExternalZoomEnabled(true);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setShowAxes(true);
      //  renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
        for (int color : colors) {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          r.setColor(color);
          renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
      }
```

**DataSet Here:**

```
 protected CategorySeries buildCategoryDataset(String title, double[] values) {
CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(title);
int k = 0,year;
String str_year;
str_year=String.valueOf(Math.round(values[0]));
Log.i("Invent","Year"+str_year);

year=Integer.parseInt(str_year);
Log.i("Invent","YearInt"+year);
    if(flag_val==1)
    {
        for(k=0;k<tot_yearno-1;k++)
        {
            if(values[k]==0)
        {  
        series.add(0.0);     /// Here some settings for display null value.But **here i Want to display nothing Only.** 
        }
            else
            series.add("" + year_first++, values[k]);   
        }
    }
    if(flag_val==0)
    {
    for (double value : values) {    

        if(value==0)
        {
        series.add("" + ++k, 0.0);
        }
        else
  series.add("Day " + ++k, value);
}
    }
return series;
        }
      }
```

Comment: why dont you just remove all entries from the array which you dont want before you pass it to the renderer object?

Comment: I think you need to re-phrase the question - why are you ADDING zero-based values? What is it that you really want to do?

Comment: Please share me if anyone known the answer for this........

Comment: Try boxing your double values in a Double object, i.e. instead of saying '0.0', say 'new Double(0.0)' - see my edited comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here:

```
 if(values[k]==0)
    {  
    series.add(0.0);     /// Here some settings for display null value.But **here i Want to display nothing Only.** 
    }
        else
        series.add("" + year_first++, values[k]);   
    }
```

You should do it like this:

```
if(values[k] != 0) //or possibly (values[k] >= 0) since you cannot show negatives either
{  
    series.add("" + year_first++, values[k]);   
}
```

**EDIT: Try this then:**

```
if(values[k]==0)
{  
    series.add("" + year_first++, new Double(0.0));      
}
else
{
    series.add("" + year_first++, new Double(values[k]));   
}
```

Comment: If i do like that then the problem occurs as renderer cannot set. So we should match with all 30 entries. I define the 30 entries via colors value for differing those 30 entries.

Comment: Try the edit - I also had a thought - you might have a boxing issue when inserting 'double' types - use the boxed 'Double' type (capitol D)

Comment: I will try via codings steps to prevent occuring null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to show 0 values, just don't add them to the dataset.

Look at the createDataSet in the PieChartView for an example - there they add the values with the label.

```
private staticPieDataSet createDataSet(){
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataset.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));
}
```

Now when you add your own values (I am not sure how you do it, but I pass them through the bundle datatype and then extract them for the following method), you can just not add based on value:

```
private staticPieDataSet createDataSet(Double[] values, String[] labels){
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if (value[i] > 0)
            dataset.setValue(labels[i], values[i]);
    }
}
```

PS!!! I wouldn't recommend this by the way - your users may become confused as to why some data shows up and others do not - rather put the value in brackets with the label so they can see this value is 0.

Comment: Thanks for Reply [Quintin Balsdon]. But it's not worked in my coding. I am using categoryseries set there is no option as set value. Please see my coding ........

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like this way, before showing the Chart View as I have done for TimeChart

```
    for(int i=0;i<selectedCollectionY.size();i++)
    {
        if(selectedCollectionY.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        {
            selectedCollectionY.remove(i);
            selectedCollectionX.remove(i);
        }
    }
    View mView = null;
    mView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(GraphActivity.this, Line_Chart
            .getLineDemoDataset(mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    selectedCollectionX, selectedCollectionY), Line_Chart
            .getLineDemoRenderer(mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()),
            "MMM dd");
    mView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    mLinearLayout.addView(mView);
```